# check arraylist from the beginning after remove an element

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

Got a List of elements:

```
String[] temp = new String[]{"NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"};
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(temp));
```

I need return to begining of the loop after removing elements from `ArrayList`

removing elements `"NORTH"` and `"SOUTH"` if they consecutive:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1 ; i++) {

    if (list.get(i).equals("NORTH") && list.get(i + 1).equals("SOUTH")) {
        list.remove(i);
        list.remove(i);
    }
    if (list.get(i).equals("SOUTH") && list.get(i + 1).equals("NORTH")) {
        list.remove(i);
        list.remove(i);
    }
```

the above code delete elements `"NORTH"` and `"SOUTH"`, and continue check elements but with this condition:

```
    if (list.get(i).equals("SOUTH") && list.get(i + 1).equals("NORTH")) {
        list.remove(i);
        list.remove(i);
    }
```

I need to back to the first condition after delete elements.

How to do it?

Comment: Try `else if` for the second, it won't do the second if the 1st has been valid

Comment: Your code works as it should. The second if doesn't run because the condition will always fail. Change you list to have consecutive values of south and north and it should work.

Comment: Can you explain a little further? What do you want to do precisely? Which is the first condition you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to reduce `i` by 1 and the continue the loop, so in the next round, when `i` gets incremented, you are back at the first `if` and `i` is the same as before:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1 ; i++) {
    if (…) {
        list.remove(i);
        list.remove(i);
        i--;
        continue;
    }
    if (…) {
        list.remove(i);
        list.remove(i);
        i--;
        continue;
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want to use the `continue` statement you can use an else-if so the second condition won't be executed for `i-1`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1 ; i++) {
    if (…) {
        list.remove(i);
        list.remove(i);
        i--;
    }
    else if (…) {
        list.remove(i);
        list.remove(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```